# Paypal PHP How to check validity of refresh token for future payments

Tags: php, paypal, authorization, token

I am working on an iOS app where I am getting user's consent for **future payments** via Paypal iOS SDK.

I get the authorization token, send it to the PHP server that gets the refresh token via Paypal PHP SDK and stores it in database.

Then for any future payments, I can use this refresh token to get a fresh access token to create the payment.

However, the payment is created at the end of the process of the app. I am wondering what happens if the user closes his Paypal account some day before the end of the process and still uses the app. The payment would be rejected, but the process would have been done (for free...)

My question is: **Is there a way to check the validity of the stored refresh token at the beginning of the process?**

I read through Paypal documentation, but I couldn't find any reference other than when the payment is done upfront.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exchange of a refresh token to an access token should fail if the account is closed.  However, this won't help you out if they closed the account after that exchange but before the payment. If you are allowing the use of the service and then payment later, I'd recommend setting up an Authorization up front. With a pending Authorization, the consumer will be unable to close their account and you would be able to do the Capture at the end of the process. If they cancel out before the end of the process or you don't want to capture the funds for whatever reason, then you can just void the authorization that you created upfront.